# Vue + php, how send array to props?

Tags: php, for-loop, vue.js

I just started to learn Vue, and I can't understand what for is props?
I have simple array in php :

```
$vegetables = ['apple', 'strawberry', 'banana'];
```

Now I want it in my blade ( laravel ), but I don't know how to do foreach now with Vue... I tryed to do like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app-7">
<ol>

    <vegetable-item
        v-for="item in vegetables"
    </vegetable-item>
</ol>
</div>

 </body>
<script>
Vue.component('#app7', {
    props: ['array'],
    template: '<li>{{ item.text }}</li>'
})
```

It completely doesn't work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't understand the difference between frontend and backend part. Your front with some vue components have no knowledge if there are any variables in php.

Vue(and any js stuff) needs the data passed to view as normal js variables: using rendering them to view as text, sending them via ajax requests...

If you want to loop through `$vegetables` array you have to render this array to html as **Burdy** posted.

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

```
<?php
    $vegetables = ['apple', 'strawberry', 'banana'];
?>

<script>
var arr = "<?php echo implode(",", $vegetables); ?>".split(",");
console.log(arr); //["apple", "strawberry", "banana"]
Vue.component('#app7', {
    props: arr,
    template: '<li>{{ item.text }}</li>'
})

</script>
```